# How can I use division in a golang template?

Tags: go

How can I use division in a golang template. I need to divide `Id` by 2.

For example

```
{{if .Id/2}}
HEY, I CAN DO IT!
{{else}}
WHY???
{{end}}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The package `text/template` (and subsequently `html/template`) can provide the functionality by defining division as a function using [`Template.Funcs`](http://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#Template.Funcs):

```
func (t *Template) Funcs(funcMap FuncMap) *Template
```

In your case, a `FuncMap` with a divide function could look something like this:

```
fm := template.FuncMap{"divide": func(a, b int) int {
    return a / b
}}
```

Full example (but without me trying to understand what you mean with `if a/2`):

```
package main

import (
    "os"
    "text/template"
)

func main() {
    fm := template.FuncMap{"divide": func(a, b int) int {
        return a / b
    }}

    tmplTxt := `{{divide . 2}}`

    // Create a template, add the function map, and parse the text.
    tmpl, err := template.New("foo").Funcs(fm).Parse(tmplTxt)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // Run the template to verify the output.
    err = tmpl.Execute(os.Stdout, 10)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

**Output:**

> 5

**Playground:** http://play.golang.org/p/VOhTYbdj6P

Comment: .... I just cant believe this is no +-*/ function in golang template after 7 years